# Using an online .txt file as a data source

Tags: android, parsing, text-files

I am building an Android app for a client and most of the data that i need is contained in an online .txt file attached to my clients website. I've never used an online .txt file as a data source before and don't really know where to begin?! Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial on the subject.

Many Thanks in advance

P.S. I haven't asked whether it's possible because i have assumed it is due to the fact you can use an internal .txt file as a data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to download the file on the device and then read it like a normal file. If the file changes on a period of time, then configure the app to download and read the file and then update the local info in the app.

I don't think you can use an online txt as a DataSource, but you can implement this so you have an abstract source for your file, and then just call read on it.

Comment: Cheers, yeah this is what i have ended up doing and seems to be the best solution. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expose the txt/xml file over web,if you want to get it down to phone use URL loader and load it to the phone and operate if you want to use it online (like others may also be using it) it will be a bit complex in order to deal with data coming from more then one source but possible. clear you question a bit more.